# Google Sheets Array If Condition

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, nested-if

I have the below formula which works fine and returns the expected results.

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(if(row(I:I)=1,"CE Credit",
    if(A:A="","",
    VLOOKUP(I:I&" "&U:U,importrange("abc123","Course Catalog Database Export!E:N"),3,0))),"!!!"))
```

I need to add a condition. If the vlookup results is greater than 0, I want it to return Yes, if not No.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(if(row(I:I)=1,"CE Certificate Needed",
if(A:A="","",
if(VLOOKUP(I:I&" "&U:U,importrange("abc123","Course Catalog Database Export!E:N"),3,0)>0,"Yes","No")),"!!!")))
```

However the header shows blank and no results are shown?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"CE Certificate Needed"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF(A2:A="",,IF((VLOOKUP(I2:I&" "&U2:U, 
 IMPORTRANGE("abc123", "Course Catalog Database Export!E:N"), 3, 0)*1)>0, "Yes", "No")), "!!!"))}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why what I did was not working as expected?

Comment: @Mark if this answer works for you then most likely the output of VLOOKUP was text so we just multiply by 1 to convert it into numeric value which can be then compared to >0